# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set') discord.js v13 slash commands handler

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating a Slash commands handler when i run the bot i get this error :
`Mainguild.SlashCommands.set(SlashComanndsArray).then(async (SlashCommand) => { TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')`
this is the code :

```
   client.on("ready", async () => {
       const Mainguild = await client.guilds.cache.get("926674245357039657");

       Mainguild.SlashCommands.set(SlashComanndsArray).then(async (SlashComanndsArray) => {
           const Roles = (SlashCommandName) => {
               const cmdPerms = SlashComanndsArray.find((c) => c.name === SlashCommandName).permission;
               if(!cmdPerms) return null;

               return Mainguild.roles.cache.filter((r) => r.permissions.has(cmdPerms));
           };
           const FullPermissions = SlashCommand.reduce((accumulator, r) => {
               const roles = Roles(r.name);
               if(!roles) return accumulator;

               const permissions = roles.reduce((a, r) => {
                   return [...a, {id: r.id, type: "ROLE", permission: true}];
               }, []);

               return [...accumulator, {id: r.id, permissions}];
           }, []);

           await Mainguild.SlashCommands.permissions.set({ FullPermissions });
       });

   })
}
```

also `SlashComanndsArray` , `SlashCommand` are defined
and for the  `SlashCommands` is a collection that i created id index.js with `client.SlashCommands = new Collection();`
the  full code : https://srcb.in/BX1Ko4LuXd
the index.js : https://srcb.in/qFC57vTaSn

Comment: `Mainguild.SlashCommands` is obviously undefined, so start by trying to figure out why that is! :)

Comment: `Mainguild.SlashCommands.permissions` is undefined. `Mainguild.SlashCommands` does exist

Comment: @Tvde1 I don't think so. What do you think `Mainguild.SlashCommands` is?

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')` means `undefined.set` meaning that `Mainguild.SlashCommands.permissions` is undefined. If `Mainguild.SlashCommands` was undefined it would tell us `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Mainguild.SlashCommands` is obviously undefined because `Guild.SlashCommands` is not a thing in discord.js
- Use [Guild#commands](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=commands) instead.

```js
Mainguild.commands
```

- Your `client.SlashCommands` is limited to your `client`. You cannot use it with a `Guild`.